# How to prevent app to publish except play store?

Tags: copyright

I have published one application to the play store around 2 years ago. it has a good user base. But my problem is that I found my app on apkpure https://apkpure.com/ also where I have never uploaded. and I do not want my app to publish anywhere except play store. How can I remove my application from that other site? please advise.

Answer (score 2):

[Apkpure says](https://apkpure.com/dmca.html) that they abide by DMCA. That link says what you must do to get them to take the infringing work down. DMCA is a whack-a-mole solution, and it is the only recourse that you have.